# asfreq() dropping data when no method specified

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe (Sal) with a 5 day time series, with a data point every 15(ish) minutes. I need to interpolate these values to estimate a value for every minute.

```
import pandas as pd
Sal = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime' : ['2020-03-02 18:58:23', '2020-03-02 19:13:22', '2020-03-02 19:28:23'], 'Salinity' : [25.5, 28, 30]})
```

I am formatting the time data (DateTime) as a time series object:

```
Sal['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(Sal['DateTime'])
```

I then specify the DateTime data as the index, expanding the data frame so there is row for every minute:

```
Sal = Sal.set_index('DateTime').asfreq('T', method = 'ffill')
```

This works, and I get a fully populated dataframe. However I don't want the filled results, but nans in order to interpolate later, so I leave the method unspecified

```
Sal = Sal.set_index('DateTime').asfreq('T')
```

This then leaves me with nan values between the data I collected, but my data disappear in the latter half of the dataframe, so I'm left with a few days of nans, not much use. Even on this small sample frame the middle  value (28) is replaced with a nan

Any suggestions as to why asfreq() is doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine **if you convert to datetime correctly**.

`'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'` is not a valid format for your data. As you have `errors = 'coerce'`, this converts to NaN without raising any error.

Use instead `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` (assuming YYYY-MM-DD, else `'%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S'` for YYYY-DD-MM):

```
Sal['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(Sal['DateTime'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors = 'coerce')
```

Comment: Hi, that's my bad on the format I provided, I'd got a bit confused copying the code across. I don't think that's caused the issue as when I specify a method (ffill or bfill) it works correctly and I don't lose any data.

Comment: @Alex can you provide your current output, the expected output and your python/pandas versions?

Comment: Will do, I'm off on a trip today for a bit, but I'll check all that and get back to you soon. Thanks for the help

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. It turns out to have been an error in the imported time data, the probe had exported some in a format that didn't work. Once I cleaned up the raw data it's all worked properly.

Comment: Glad you found out, you might want to delete the question as it's probably of little use to the community (other than reminding to carefully double check the data) ;)